# Having issue writing a simple mathematical equation in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I have the following pseudocode below,

```
procedure optimal():
  for each i in 1 · · · N do
     TMi ← fmobile(i)
     TCi ← fcloud(i)
     TUi ← Di/B
     return [psuedocode][1]
```

I am trying to convert it in python. I have written the following code

```
 def optimal():
   B=20
   for i in range(1, 10):
     latency_m=[]
     latency_c=[]
     transfer_latency=[]
     total_latency_m = 0
     total_latency_c=0
     latency_m[i]=estimate_m(i)
     latency_c[i]=estimate_c(i)
     transfer_latency[i]=estimate_output(i)/B

    for j in range (1, 10):

        for i in range(1,j):
            total_latency_e+=latency_e[i]

        for k in range(j+1,10):
            total_latency_c+=latency_c[k]
```

Thanks for your help.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXNQX.gif

Comment: It's not at all clear what your pseudocode is describing, could you provide more context

Comment: Are you trying to find j such that the sum in the image is minimized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the formula attached:

```
N = 50

TM = [] # External source
TC = [] # External source
TU = [] # External source

SUMS = [0] * N
for j in range(N):
    for i in range(1, j+1):
        SUMS[j] += TM[i]
    for k in range(j-1, N+1):
        SUMS[j] += TC[k]    
    SUMS[j] += TU[j]
    
return min(SUMS)
```

Comment: Hi @AvivYaniv, I am getting an error while I run your code  for i in range(i, j + 1):
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment